# Mutual Authentication in Scala with Akka

Tags: scala, ssl, akka, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

I would create a TLS Session in Scala using Akka with mutual authentication between a client and a server. I have created two CA certificate that have to trust the respective certificates incoming from the other part.
Could you give me an exemple of how implement this?
Thank you.

Comment: There are good examples in Akka doc: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html#mutual-authentication

Comment: If this is about akka-http, look at what @EmiCareOfCell44 posted. Otherwise, maybe you aren't talking about an HTTPS connection? Is this about a plain TLS/TCP connection? Or about akka-remote? All of those can use TLS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a github project which demonstrates mutual authentication with different kind of clients, including Akka. Please have a look here: https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl

It contains a full example of loading the ssl material into the client and server

A summary what you need to do is:

- For the client

  - Create a key and a certificate and load it into a keystore
  - Export the certificate
  - Create a separate keystore for trusted certificates and import server certificate
  - Load the two keystores into your http client
- For the server

  - Create a key and a certificate and load it into a keystore
  - Export the certificate
  - Create a separate keystore for trusted certificates and import client certificate
  - Load the two keystores into your server

It is not really clear to me what kind of server you are using, but if you are using spring-boot the example configuration would be:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:identity.jks
    key-password: secret
    key-store-password: secret
    trust-store: classpath:truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: secret
    client-auth: need
```

Akka requires a pre-configured instance of SSLContext to be able to configure HTTPS. An example of creating a client with https options would be the code snippet below.

```java
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.http.javadsl.ConnectionContext;
import akka.http.javadsl.Http;
import akka.http.javadsl.HttpsConnectionContext;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.util.Optional;

class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(
                App.class.getSimpleName(),
                ConfigFactory.defaultApplication(App.class.getClassLoader())
        );

        SSLContext sslContext = ...; //Initialized SSLContext

        Http http = Http.get(actorSystem);
        HttpsConnectionContext httpsContext = ConnectionContext.https(
                sslContext,
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.of(sslContext.getDefaultSSLParameters()));
        http.setDefaultClientHttpsContext(httpsContext);
    }
}
```

There are couple of libraries which provides easy to use utility/factory/builder classes to help you to create a SSLContext.

- [Apache SSLContextBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html)
- [Jetty SslContextFactory](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.14.v20181114/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html)
- [SSLContext-Kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart)

There could be a bunch other libraries which provide similar functionality, but I am only aware of these three. By the way the sslcontext-kickstart is a library which is maintained by me.

Below is an overview of four ways to load the keystores and create an SSLContext. Vanilla Java and by using the three libraries.

```java
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import nl.altindag.sslcontext.SSLFactory;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Objects;

class SslExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Traditional flow of creating sslContext
        String keyStorePath = "keystore.p12";
        String trustStorePath = "truststore.p12";

        char[] keyStorePassword = "secret".toCharArray();
        char[] trustStorePassword = "secret".toCharArray();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

        try(InputStream keyStoreInputStream = SslExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyStorePath);
            InputStream trustStoreInputStream = SslExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(trustStorePath)) {

            Objects.requireNonNull(keyStoreInputStream);
            Objects.requireNonNull(trustStoreInputStream);

            keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword);
            trustStore.load(trustStoreInputStream, trustStorePassword);
        }

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

        //creating sslContext with Apache SSLContextBuilder
        SSLContext sslContext1 = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(new File("keystore.p12"), "secret".toCharArray(), "secret".toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File("truststore.p12"), "secret".toCharArray())
                .build();

        //creating sslContext with Jetty SslContextFactory
        SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("keystore.p12");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath("truststore.p12");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.start();

        SSLContext sslContext2 = sslContextFactory.getSslContext();

        //creating sslContext with sslcontext-kickstart
        SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
                .withIdentity("keystore.p12", "secret".toCharArray())
                .withTrustStore("truststore.p12", "secret".toCharArray())
                .build();

        SSLContext sslContext3 = sslFactory.getSslContext();
    }

}
```

It is in java, but IntelliJ Idea provides a handy translate function to scala when pasting the code snippet.