# How to use SSL Certificates in Spring Boot application to call remote API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, ssl

This is a topic that has taken me quite some time to figure out. There are bits and pieces of information scattered and one has to put everything together. I was hoping that with this post I could help others quickly assemble a working solution.

I have a `certificate.pem`, `key.pem`. I need to use them in my Java client to access a remote REST API using JERSEY client.

Things I tried so far:

**Converted pem files into JKS.**

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey key.pem -out client.jks -passout pass:CLIENT -name myClient`

**Added to truststore**

`keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore truststore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass CLIENT -srckeystore pathtoJKS://client.jks -srcstorepass CLIENT -srcstoretype JKS`

**Added properties as below**

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=client.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=CLIENT
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=CLIENT
```

but for some reason the remote API still thinks like, I'm not sending the correct certificates.

Can someone help me what's missing here?

**EDIT :-** Added the code of the  HTTP client.

```
String keyStorePath = "client.jks"; // File is present in main/resources folder
String trustStorePath = "truststore.jks"; // File is present in main/resources folder

char[] keyStorePassword = "CLIENT".toCharArray();
char[] trustStorePassword = "CLIENT".toCharArray();

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

try(InputStream keyStoreInputStream = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyStorePath);
    InputStream trustStoreInputStream = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(trustStorePath)) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(keyStoreInputStream);
    Objects.requireNonNull(trustStoreInputStream);

    keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword);
    trustStore.load(trustStoreInputStream, trustStorePassword);
}

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslcontext.init(keyManagers,trustManagers, new java.security.SecureRandom());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .sslContext(sslcontext)
    .hostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHostNameVerifier())
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if adding the keystore/truststore properties in that way will work. I am used to configuring the client configuration directly while creating an instance, and that works for sure.

Below is an example Jersey SSL Client configuration:

```java
SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
    .withIdentityMaterial("client.jks", "CLIENT".toCharArray())
    .withTrustMaterial("truststore.jks", "CLIENT".toCharArray())
    .build();

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .sslContext(sslFactory.getSslContext())
    .hostnameVerifier(sslFactory.getHostnameVerifier())
    .build();
```

Jersey requires a configured instance of SSLContext. The above example uses SSLFactory  from [SSLContext Kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart), which is maintained by me. There are also other ways to create an instance of SSLContext, see here for all the possible ways I know: [Mutual Authentication in Scala with Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868096/mutual-authentication-in-scala-with-akka/61945168#61945168)

Could you try the above snippet and drop here the results of it?

Comment: Thanks, let me try it and keep you posted

Comment: It worked, but it is leading to a new problem. I do have 2 remote calls, one of them needed to be in https and another one is just http. Following the above approach is leading to second http call failing. Any suggestions how to set in sslContext in such cases? Sorry for not posting the right question at the first place

Comment: Great to hear that it is partly working. What is the exception message you are getting? And could you also share some code snippets on how you are making the http request within your main question, so we can get a bit more context to help you better.

Comment: So here is the exception which I'm getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` And I have added the snippet of the HTTP client  to the original question

Comment: Just to make things clear. The `HTTP` request is passing and the `HTTPS` request is still failing right?

Comment: Okay, the provided exception is a generic one, but you can get the detailed one if you start your application with the following VM arguments: `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake` Could you try that and past the full log within your main question? In that way we can see every step within the handshake proces and see at which step exactly it fails with the reason. I am not quite sure which jdk version you are using, but if you are using jdk 11 than you will also get more details

Comment: Thanks!.It worked, had to tweak a little bit according to the custom application logic we had. Thanks again, your source gave me the correct approach. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Please share your source code with us, because its problematic to trace the problem that you are currently facing. At first glance, your configuration files are good. However, there are some small improvements you can do:

- Make sure that `javax.net.ssl` are defined during runtime
- Try to specify an absolute path

Comment: This is not an answer. Please keep this kind of suggestions/comments as comments.